# Conversion from Multi-Byte encoding to Unicode

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, mfc, multibyte

I am working on a project, this contains a mix of C++, MFC and C# projects which are in need of conversion from MultiByte encoding to Unicode.

The project is too huge to do it manually.
Is there any tool to do this conversion?

Comment: Which IDE do you use to handle these projects?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend strongly against TCHAR, std::wstring, wchar_t, T() macros and L"" strings.

Summary of my views, also some guidelines for easy conversion without having to replace much of your code is in http://utf8everywhere.org.

We applied this to several large (millions CL) codebase(s) and it was rather smooth.